# Windows 10 - how to completely disable the LAN port when either ethernet cable is plugged out or WiFi is connected

Tags: windows-10, security, ethernet

To remove the possible local attack vector via Ethernet in case someone gains physical access, I want my Windows 10 laptop behave as follows:

When I have an active LAN cable connection and I disconnect the cable, I want the interface to turn off so that I can only connect again when I enable the interface in the adapters section in networking settings.

Also, if I connect to a WiFi, at that moment, I also want the Ethernet port to be disabled completely.

Is there a group policy or existing script you know which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: If somebody has physical access to your PC then it is game over trying to prevent access. Disabling the LAN port is pointless as there are many other attack vectors that cannot be prevented.

Comment: That does not mean that you don't have to do attack surface minimization.
My laptop is encrypted, I have a BIOS password for all kinds of access to it, I have backups, so the basic things are already fixed.
Network is a very problematic attack vector. An attacker might just add a rouge router to the network switch and unplug and quickly replug you cable while you're just getting coffee.